# blobtrigger not working when published on azure functions, but it working in local environment

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger

My azure function not trigger after upload my file to corresponding storage account container, but this is working fine when I test my local with following settings.

I had to use local.setting.json like below

```
"Values": {
....
"AzureWebJobsStorage" : "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
"AzureStorageMyUpload" : "<<My storage account access key, 
which is get copy from my container>>"
.....
}
```

I real time "AzureWebJobsStorage" value is another one storage account information

`"AzureStorageMyUpload" : "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<<ACCOUNT_NAME>>;AccountKey=<<ACCOUNT_KEY>>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"`

and

`"AzureStorageMyUpload" : "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<<ACCOUNT_NAME>>;AccountKey=<<ACCOUNT_KEY>>;BlobEndpoint=https://<<ACCOUNT_NAME>>.blob.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://<<ACCOUNT_NAME>>.table.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://<<ACCOUNT_NAME>>.queue.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://<<ACCOUNT_NAME>>.file.core.windows.net/"`

My azure function below

```
[FunctionName("UploadCSV")]
public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("<<containerName>>/<<folderName>>/{name}.csv", 
Connection = "AzureStorageMyUpload")]
            Stream stream, string name, ILogger log){
              log.LogInformation("UploadCSV starts");
    }
```

**Function**

Runtime version: 1.0.12922.0 (~1)

When I was created new blob trigger from the azure portal itself, it is working fine for me. the same one is not working when I create from local with help of visual studio code 2019 in azure portal it's seems like "function.json".

Comment: Did you set the `AzureStorageMyUpload` value in the app settings?

Comment: yes I am added my storage account information, like DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<<account name>>;AccountKey=<<access key>>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net

Comment: and also i tried like 
"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<<accountName>>;AccountKey=<<accountKey>>;BlobEndpoint=https://<<accountName>>.blob.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://<<accountName>>.table.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://<<accountName>>.queue.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://<<accountName>>.file.core.windows.net/"

Comment: Did you have `AzureWebJobsStorage` setting and do you have any error shown in the azure portal?

Comment: I am use "AzureWebJobsStorage" : "UseDevelopmentStorage=true" only my testing purpose, not for real time.

Comment: I real time "AzureWebJobsStorage" value is another one storage account information

Comment: How are you hosting your Function; on a Consumption Plan, App Service Plan or Premium plan? If on an App Service plan, is Always On enabled? How long was your Function deployed before you uploaded a blob? How long did you wait for the trigger to kick off your Function? I have a LOT of questions :p You could look into using [Event Grid](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/event-grid/) if triggers don't do what you need them to do.

Comment: @rickvdbosch ,

with the help of azure CICD pipe. 

this is company account I don't know which plan is it, but when ever the release was completed it automatically updated. 

it takes 5 to 10 min along with all other service and UI. 

I try to upload a file through rest API and also tried using direct blob upload.

Comment: thank you guys, your suggestion, thanks

Comment: Again i got the same issue, can any one help me out.  it's too headache to resolve. I though blob trigger is related to some configuration in storage account

Comment: @RajamohanAnguchamy, is it a v1 or v2 function? and can you attach a screenshot of the Application settings of the function in azure portal?

Comment: I am already added info 

Runtime version: 1.0.12922.0 (~1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working now, I just removed connection string name and replay to

```
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "<<live storage account details>>"


[FunctionName("UploadCSV")]
public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("<<containerName>>/<<folderName>>/{name}.csv", 
Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]
            Stream stream, string name, ILogger log){
              log.LogInformation("UploadCSV starts");
    }
```

Comment: Hi  @Rajamohan Anguchamy  i am also facing same issue can you help me out ?